# How do i advance my research career and publish papers without university affiliation?

Tags: publications, research-process, career-path, independent-researcher

I am a recent masters grad from a US institution as a foreign student. As of now I have no university affiliation. My work as a grad student was mainly research oriented. Hence now looking for a job seems redundant as many research jobs in US require US citizenship or field experience. So as a researcher my options are limited. Nevertheless I am working on a theoretical paper. The question is

1. What are my options at this point considering an academic career where I could become a teacher/lecturer/professor or academician carrying out scientific work.
2. If I have a paper ready how do i publish it in a good journal with a decent impact factor without a university affiliation.

I could not find published research in reputed journals by any independent scholars.

Comment: I think you need to demonstrate that US citizenship or field experience are required. I hire plenty of non-citizens to do research work who have no field (presumably meaning outdoors with grass or a forest or something similar) experience who are non-citizens. Field experience isn't even a recognized concept in my *ahem* field. What area of study are you talking about?

Comment: My background is in electronics and electrical engineering and my masters is in Nanoscience. My current research is in the field of theoretical condensed matter physics and quantum dynamics at a nanoscale.

Comment: This question is a potential duplicate for many SE questions, [tagged](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independent-researcher) `independent-researcher`, i.e., [this](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11937/12391), [this](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/9718/12391) and [this](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/9611/12391).

Comment: Please ask [one question per post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/welcome-to-academia-se/1204#1204)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**: Simply write your paper and submit it and wait for feedback. If it is good enough a conference will publish it.

**Longer Answer**: A contribution is a contribution, and conferences and journals are always hungry for a good content. Affiliation does not mean much, as most high ranking conferences only allow double-blind submissions; and after acceptance you can put your name, email and the company you are working for. You then will be considered an independent researcher on the subject matter. I have seen many submissions from big to small companies over the years, on subjects that were important to them and their work, who decided to submit their contribution to a research conference and get feedback.